# Behavior of Spark SQL window order by

Tags: apache-spark

I have a simple table that has 3 columns ,`depName, empNo, salary`, when I run the following window query

```
val ws = Window.partitionBy("depName").orderBy("empNo")

ds.withColumn("avg", avg("salary") over ws).show()
```

it outputs the following result,it shows that the salary avg within the depName is from the first row to the current. How could this happen? I thought that all the avg with one deptName should be same.

If I don't user `orderBy("empNo")` to create the ws, then all the avg with one deptName are the same.

I would ask how this happens, thanks.

```
 +---------+-----+------+-----------------+
|  depName|empNo|salary|              avg|
+---------+-----+------+-----------------+
|  develop|    7|  4200|           4200.0|
|  develop|    8|  6000|           5100.0|
|  develop|    9|  4500|           4900.0|
|  develop|   10|  5200|           4975.0|
|  develop|   11|  5200|           5020.0|
|    sales|    1|  5000|           5000.0|
|    sales|    3|  4800|           4900.0|
|    sales|    4|  4800|4866.666666666667|
|personnel|    2|  3900|           3900.0|
|personnel|    5|  3500|           3700.0|
+---------+-----+------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Why do you actually need orderBy here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with the below syntax. This will work as you expected as it will find the average by partitioning according to the `depName` and order by `empNo`

```
df.withColumn("avg_Time", avg($"salary").over(Window.partitionBy($"depName"))).orderBy("empNo").show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @sarath-avanavu for the helpful answer

Answer (score 4):

The `AVG()` window function operates on the rows defined in the window and returns a value for each row. The query with `AVG()` returns one row with the average of all the values in the specified column instead of returning values for each row.

The `PARTITION BY` clause subdivides the window into partitions. The `ORDER BY` clause defines the logical order of the rows within each partition of the result set. Window functions are applied to each rows, as and when it is returned after ordering within each partition. That is the reason why it is returning a running average than a total average.

As per github documentation,

> - @note When ordering is not defined, an unbounded window frame (rowFrame, unboundedPreceding, unboundedFollowing) is used by default. When ordering is defined, a growing window frame(rangeFrame, unboundedPreceding, currentRow) is used by default.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1d95dea30788b9f64c5e304d908b85936aafb238/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Window.scala#L36

Answer (score 0):

As [@Gladiator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55519479/8354249) explained, you can achieve this by specifying different bounds (in order to make running avg = total avg).

It will give you the same result for all rows within one window partition and the rows will be sorted by "empNo".

```
val ws = Window.partitionBy("depName")
      .orderBy("empNo")
      .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

ds.withColumn("avg", avg("salary") over ws).show(false)
```

The result:

```
+---------+-----+------+-----------------+
|depName  |empNo|salary|avg              |
+---------+-----+------+-----------------+
|develop  |7    |4200  |5020.0           |
|develop  |8    |6000  |5020.0           |
|develop  |9    |4500  |5020.0           |
|develop  |10   |5200  |5020.0           |
|develop  |11   |5200  |5020.0           |
|sales    |1    |5000  |4866.666666666667|
|sales    |3    |4800  |4866.666666666667|
|sales    |4    |4800  |4866.666666666667|
|personnel|2    |3900  |3700.0           |
|personnel|5    |3500  |3700.0           |
+---------+-----+------+-----------------+
```